# Find the Average of Groups of numbers in a range based on their proximity to each other in Excel

Tags: excel, average

Column A has a range of numbers.  I would like to compare each number to every other number in Column A.  I would like an average for each number of all the values that have a difference of less than 2. The desired output would be in column B.

This is the desired output:

[image: This is the desired output]

I've tried many versions of this: `=AVERAGEIF(A:A,ABS((A:A)-A9)<2,A:A)` and get a #SPILL! error.  Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decide whether it is a condition `<2` or `<=2`.
The expected results point to the latter option.
Formula that can be used in `B1` (copy down as required)

```
=AVERAGE(IF(INDEX(ABS($A$1:$A$5-TRANSPOSE($A$1:$A$5)),,ROW(B1))<2,$A$1:$A$5))
```

Change to `<=2` if necessary.
[image: Average2]

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Thank you so much for the help.  I never would have gotten there on my own.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no version constraints as per your tags, you can enter either:

```
=AVERAGE(FILTER($A$2:$A$6,ABS(A2-$A$2:$A$6)<=2))
```

and fill down.

Or, if you also have the `LAMDA` and `BYROW` functions, you can enter, in just a single cell:

```
=BYROW($A$2:$A$6,LAMBDA(arr,AVERAGE(FILTER($A$2:$A$6,ABS(arr-A2:A6)<=2))))
```

and the results will fill down automatically.

Do not use the second formula if your data is in a **Table**. Just enter the first formula in the first row and the Table will fill it down.

[image]